# How to prevent multi point touch in Android

Tags: android

In my screen, I'm having a list view and horizontal slide menu. When I touch move horizontally, the sliding menu will come and when I scroll down the list, it is working fine. But when I touch move for sliding menu with one finger and tries to scroll down the list with other finger at the same time, the screen seems to be flickering.

The issue seems to be coz of Multitouch, so how can I prevent it like : If I am scrolling the list, the other should not work and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
e.getPointerId(pointerIndex)
```

where e is MotionEvent

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a view pager?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Or, you can use a `GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` and override the onFling() method in it